# Modifying .htaccess by php code

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is there any way to modify `.htaccess` using php code?

I simply tried

```
$handle=fopen("./dir/.htaccess",w);
fwrite($handle, "order deny,allow\ndeny from all");
fclose($handle);
```

and this doesn't seems to work.

P.S. I can't use the `RewriteMap` in `httpd.conf` as I don't have root permissions.

Comment: What are the file permissions? What user is PHP run as? What error messages are you receiving? Try putting `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your code.

Comment: php runs as 'apache'; and file permission is 755

Comment: If permission is 755, unless it is owned by 'apache' you won't be able to write to it.

Comment: @Mike thanks, i changed permission to 777 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is correct. Only problem is that the user that runs the php is `apache`. I checked that out using `whoami` command. So file permission needs to be changed accordingly.

Changing file permission to 777 worked perfectly.
Thanks to Mike

Comment: 777 permissions are like leaving your front door unlocked. Note that any other user sharing your server can now overwrite your .htaccess file. Change it back to 644 or 444 until you need to change it again. Consider putting codes within .htaccess itself to limit access to it by web visitors (that won't secure it against others on your system, though).

Comment: @PhilPerry I understand the risk though. Since the .htaccess I need to modify is the leaf level .htaccess. So it won't affect my whole site but just a directory. I calculated the risk before using this.

Comment: OK, so long as you understand the potential consequences of leaving a file or directory open for anyone to write to. I gave the advice because all too often, I see people trying to be helpful to newbies, starting out their instructions with "first chmod everything to 777". That may have been OK 40 years ago, but the Golden Rule on any computer is "don't trust anyone else any more than you have to".

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can modify the `.htaccess` using the PHP code.

You could do like this..

```
$handle=fopen(".htaccess",'a'); //<--- Surround the 'a' with quotes. You didn't do that btw
fwrite($handle, "order deny,allow\ndeny from all");
fclose($handle);
```

Try to run this code from the very same location where your `.htaccess` is.

Comment: If it didn't work with 'w', it probably wouldn't work with 'a' either since the only thing that changes is the file pointer position. Also, if you use a non-quoted string it will still work as expected, but will produce a warning if error reporting is on.

Comment: If you closely notice my code, I had changed the location of the `.htacccess` , I think OP is referring a non-existent `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. You could very well be right.